# Solving Recurrence Relation 5

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve the recurrence relation given by the equation below

$$T(n)=T(n-2)+T(n-4)+T(n-6)+...+T(0)$$

It seems to me that $T(n)$ will be exponential but i don't know how to proceed on this problem.

Comment: What are $T(0)$ and $T(1)$?

Comment: You can simplify the above as $T_n=2T_{n-2}$

Comment: Your recurrence only works for $n$ even. You should also provide one for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$T_2=T_0$

$T_4=T_2+T_0=2T_0$

$T_6=T_4+T_2+T_0=2T_4=2^2T_0$

.

.

$T_n=2T_{n-2}=2^{\frac{n}{2}-1}T_0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $T(0)$=1, then $T(2)=1=2^0$, $T(4)=2=2^1$, $T(6)=4=2^2$, $T(8)=8=2^3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the given recurrence in a more traditional form:

$$T(n+2)=\color{green}{T(n)}+\color{blue}{T(n-2)+T(n-4)+T(n-6)+...+T(0)}=\color{green}{T(n)}+\color{blue}{T(n)}.$$

The solution is obviously

$$T(n)=C2^{n/2}$$ *for even, positive $n$*.

With the initial condition

$$T(2)=T(0),$$

we have
$$T(n)=2^{n/2-1}T(0)$$ where $T(0)$ is assumed to be known.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $T(n-2)=T(n-4)+T(n-6)+T(n-8)+...T(0)$

Answer (score -1):

Let $S(k) = T(2 k).$ Then
$S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} S(k),$ which will grow exponentially with base $2.$

Similarly, define $R(k) = T(2k+1).$ This will satisfy the same recurrence, with the same solution, so your thing grows like $2^{n/2}.$

Comment: You have no information about the values at odd numbers, there is nothing you can deduce.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why don't I have information about the values at odd numbers? Because you have reading comprehension issues?

Comment: What do you know about $T(1)$  ? About $T(3)$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The OP says nothing about initial conditions of any kind, so what do you know abut $T(0)?$ Or $T(2)?$

Comment: The recurrence says $T(2)=T(0)$. There is no equivalent for odd terms. Unless you read a different text than me.